# DirectX 9 wrapper to force resolution and screen

Tags: wrapper, directx-9

Is there a generic DirectX 9 wrapper that can force widescreen resolution on old games? (I know that for most games the ui will break in horrible ways ^^, but maybe i get lucky on some)

Additional it would be nice if it can also force a specific screen in a multi monitor setup for exclusive fullscreen. (But I'm not sure if this is something DirectX manages?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dgVoodoo:
http://dege.freeweb.hu/dgVoodoo2/dgVoodoo2.html

However some browser declare it as imho false positive see e.g. the post of a malwarebytes reasearch engineer https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/183073-dgvoodoo-2-false-positive/?tab=comments#comment-1039768